# Do all SELECT statement together

Tags: mysql, sql, select

***Tables:***

```
*shots*
id user_id cat_id name extension size title description library created updated
```

This table includes all images

---

```
favorites
id shot_id user_id date
```

This table holds all added favorite images of users

---

```
stars
id shot_id user_id date
```

This table holds all given stars to images of users

---

```
views
id shot_id user_id date
```

This tables includes every view of each user

---

```
points
id shot_id count date
```

Every action of the users (addFavvorite, giveStar, viewShot) adds points to the specific shot

---

**Is it possible to do the following queries in a single one?**

```
SELECT * FROM shots WHERE id = ?
```

Gets the informations of a single shot.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM favorites WHERE shot_id = ?
```

Gets Count of Users who added a shot to their favorites

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM star WHERE shot_id = ?
```

Gets Count of Users who give a Star

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE shot_id = ?
```

Gets count of who visited this shot

```
SELECT AVG(count) AS attention FROM points WHERE shot_id = ? AND date > DATE_SUB(DATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) ORDER BY shot_id
```

Current Attention of the shot (average gained points in last two days)

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS attention FROM points WHERE shot_id = ? ORDER BY shot_id
```

Popularity of shot (points since upload of shot)

---

**And how can I select shots after the attention and popularity criteria ( e.g. to show every shot who have a attention bigger than 40, or habe the popularity bigger than 100 )**

Comment: If you would use proper `JOIN`s and `GROUP BY` than it would be possible. Without any analisys i can tell you to join all required tables and group by `shot_id`. That sould be close to the result you expecting.

Comment: @OP please do not over format _a question_ it really looks _ugly_

Comment: I tried this query, but I doesn't retrieve the counts:SELECT s.*, u.username, u.fullname, c.title AS ctitle,c.description AS cdescription, COUNT(f.id) AS favorites,COUNT(st.id) AS stars,COUNT(v.id) AS views FROM shots s
                INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
                INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = s.cat_id
                INNER JOIN favorites f ON f.shot_id = s.id
                INNER JOIN stars st ON st.shot_id = s.id
                INNER JOIN views v ON v.shot_id = s.id
                WHERE s.id = :shotId

Comment: you can use the UNION query statement but has the limitation that every query must have same number of selected fileds.

Comment: @Matteo sry, but that is in my opinion not possible ..

Comment: I propose something like: ` SELECT 'Star: ', COUNT(*) FROM star WHERE shot_id = ?
UNION
SELECT 'Views: ', COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE shot_id = ?
union
SELECT 'attention: ', AVG(count) AS attention FROM points WHERE shot_id = ? AND date > DATE_SUB(DATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) ORDER BY shot_id
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basic need could be done like this:-

```
SELECT s.id,
    s.user_id,
    s.cat_id,
    s.name,
    s.extension,
    s.size,
    s.title,
    s.description,
    s.library,
    s.created,
    s.updated,
    u.username,
    u.fullname,
    c.title AS ctitle,
    c.description AS cdescription,
    COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) AS favorites,
    COUNT(DISTINCT st.id) AS stars,
    COUNT(DISTINCT v.id) AS views
FROM shots s
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = s.cat_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN favorites f ON f.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN stars st ON st.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN views v ON v.shot_id = s.id
WHERE s.id = 18
GROUP BY s.id,
    s.user_id,
    s.cat_id,
    s.name,
    s.extension,
    s.size,
    s.title,
    s.description,
    s.library,
    s.created,
    s.updated,
    u.username,
    u.fullname,
    ctitle,
    cdescription
ORDER BY s.id
```

LEFT OUTER JOINs used as for a shot it would seem that there may not be a favourite / star / view, and with an inner join one of these missing would result in no record being returned.

It also uses *COUNT(DISTINCT ...)* as there could be multiple favorites for a shot, so favorite id could appear multiple times (this is because the query gets every combination of possible favorites, stars and views).

To add the 2nd part of your question, this can be done with a couple of sub queries.

If you are retrieving details for many shots then probably fastest to do this by joining against the sub queries:-

```
SELECT s.id,
    s.user_id,
    s.cat_id,
    s.name,
    s.extension,
    s.size,
    s.title,
    s.description,
    s.library,
    s.created,
    s.updated,
    u.username,
    u.fullname,
    c.title AS ctitle,
    c.description AS cdescription,
    sub_att.current_attention,
    sub_pop.popularity,
    COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) AS favorites,
    COUNT(DISTINCT st.id) AS stars,
    COUNT(DISTINCT v.id) AS views
FROM shots s
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = s.cat_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT shot_id, AVG(count) AS current_attention 
    FROM points 
    WHERE date > DATE_SUB(DATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    GROUP BY shot_id
) sub_att ON sub_att.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT shot_id, SUM(count) AS popularity
    FROM points 
    GROUP BY shot_id
) sub_pop ON sub_pop.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN favorites f ON f.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN stars st ON st.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN views v ON v.shot_id = s.id
WHERE s.id = 18
GROUP BY s.id,
    s.user_id,
    s.cat_id,
    s.name,
    s.extension,
    s.size,
    s.title,
    s.description,
    s.library,
    s.created,
    s.updated,
    u.username,
    u.fullname,
    ctitle,
    cdescription,
    sub_att.current_attention,
    sub_pop.popularity
ORDER BY s.id
```

For a single shot then probably best to just put the sub queries in the SELECT part of the statement (this way it forces the sub queries to be performed once each for each returned row, which with a lot of records being returned will be inefficient):-

```
SELECT s.id,
    s.user_id,
    s.cat_id,
    s.name,
    s.extension,
    s.size,
    s.title,
    s.description,
    s.library,
    s.created,
    s.updated,
    u.username,
    u.fullname,
    c.title AS ctitle,
    c.description AS cdescription,
    (
        SELECT AVG(count) AS current_attention 
        FROM points 
        WHERE shot_id = s.id AND date > DATE_SUB(DATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    ) AS current_attention,
    (
        SELECT SUM(count) AS popularity
        FROM points 
        WHERE shot_id = s.id 
    ) AS popularity,
    COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) AS favorites,
    COUNT(DISTINCT st.id) AS stars,
    COUNT(DISTINCT v.id) AS views
FROM shots s
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = s.cat_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN favorites f ON f.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN stars st ON st.shot_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN views v ON v.shot_id = s.id
WHERE s.id = 18
GROUP BY s.id,
    s.user_id,
    s.cat_id,
    s.name,
    s.extension,
    s.size,
    s.title,
    s.description,
    s.library,
    s.created,
    s.updated,
    u.username,
    u.fullname,
    ctitle,
    cdescription,
    sub_att.current_attention,
    sub_pop.popularity
ORDER BY s.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appretiate your help so much. The first suggested query works, but the 2nd and the 3rd doesn! Theres a problem with the subquerys ...

Comment: Sry, a fault of me. its ´curdate() not date()´!